# Could not autowire Spring data JPA repository

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I was learning Spring data JPA via a sample application(following a tutorial at [enter link description here](http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-data-jpa-tutorial-part-two-crud/)) but got stuck at getting my JPA repository to work.

Product repository(Product is an entity)

```
@Repository
public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product , Long> {

}
```

ProductRepositoryImpl

```
public class ProductRepositoryImpl {

    @Autowired
    private ProductRepository productRepo;

    /**
     * @return the productRepo
     */
    public ProductRepository getProductRepo() {
        return productRepo;
    }

    /**
     * @param productRepo the productRepo to set
     */
    public void setProductRepo(ProductRepository productRepo) {
        this.productRepo = productRepo;
    }

    public Product findOne(Long id) {
        return productRepo.findOne(id);
    }
}
```

Spring configurations

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd">

    <repositories base-package="com.springtest" />
    <jpa:repositories base-package="com.springtest.repository"/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.springtest"/>
</beans:beans>
```

Main class

```
public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();

        ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder()
            .applySettings(configuration.getProperties())
            .buildServiceRegistry();
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);

        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();

        ProductRepositoryImpl productService = new ProductRepositoryImpl();
        Product product = productService.findOne(1L);
        session.close();
    }
}
```

But every time I run this, I get **`null` for `productRepo`**. Can anyone please tell me what am i missing here?

Edit: Created an implementation class for autowiring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring can only inject beans into other Spring beans, created by Spring. You create your instance of MainClass using

```
new MainClass()
```

So Spring is totally unaware of the existence of this object and can't magically inject anything into this object.

You need to create a Spring context, ask it for a bean, and then use this bean.

Read the [introduction to Spring](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html) in the documentation.

Comment: Please read my edited post. I have now created an implementation class to allow autowiring but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Re-read my answer, and read the documentation I linked to. You're still not creating a Spring application context, and you're still not asking the context for a bean, but you're still creating an object with new and expecting Spring to autowire it.